# query, where field contains 2 t's

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard, where-clause

is there a way to perform a where clause that will match only 2 t's independent off where they are located.

such as

Matthew --
would work

Thanatos --
would work

Thanatos T --
would not work

Tom --
would not work

I've been Googling but cant find anything specific about this

any help is apreciated

Comment: have you tried `LIKE '%t%t%' AND NOT LIKE '%t%t%t%'` ?

Comment: hmm didn't think of that, thought '%t%t%t%' would stop 3 t's but fail at stopping 4 t's or more. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Field LIKE '%t%t%' AND Field NOT LIKE '%t%t%t%'
```

I'm curious which would be faster, this or Goat CO's answer.

Comment: whether which one is faster i don't know, but hatchets answer seems to work fine form me. I tested it with up to 6 t's and it still produced the proper results thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LEN()` and `REPLACE()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE LEN(REPLACE(field,'t','tt')) - LEN(Field) = 2
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad278/2/0)

Comment: This does not work with a name like "Bob T". In my test, SQL Server also removed the trailing space, resulting in it passing the test. But if it weren't for that, this was a little faster than my answer.

Comment: @hatchet . . . The simple fix to that is to do:  `len(replace(field, 't', 'tt')) - len(field) = 2`.